Why is this conclusion of Gaussian distribution valid?
My book derives this formula of a random variable's pdf:
$$C*exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2)$$
Then jumps to the conclusion that this variable comes from a normal distribution of $(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Meanwhile, the formula for a normal distribution pdf is strictly:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}*exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2)$$
How is this a valid argument?
Can someone please explain this.

Well, these are the same thing.  "C" is a constant, so when $$C=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma}$$ the two expressions are equal.  Since, for a pdf, the integral of the pdf must equal 1, "C" must be this value.

$$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp \left\{ -\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \right)^2 \right\} = \sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma$$
$$\Longrightarrow C = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}.$$

You have to choose $C$ such that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}C\exp\left(-\frac12\left(\frac{x-\mu}\sigma\right)^2\right)\,dx = 1$$
Since dropping $C$ the integral equals $\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma$, $C=1/\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma$.

Thanks :D. The question is already answered!

@MathematicsBeginner oh, sorry, I didn't notice.
